# Heredoc statement showing syntax error

Tags: php, heredoc

Why am I getting a "unexpected end of file" syntax error? The error appears to be after the closing "?>" line but I can't find anything wrong with it.

```
<?php

require_once("classPage.php");

$page = new Page();

print $page->getTop();

print <<<EOF

<div id="mainContent">

<p>This is where content would go, should there be any.</p>

</div> <!-- end main content -->

EOF; // no space at start of this line

print $page->getBottom();

?>
<---- Error is here.
```

Comment: What line are you getting the error at? (please also mark the line in your code)

Comment: The error is outside the closing "?>". I've removed the spacing before the "EOF;" but the error is still there.

Answer (score 2):

Your code should be something like this, note that comment in code.

```
<?php

    require_once("classPage.php");

    $page = new Page();

    print $page->getTop();

    print <<<EOF

<div id="mainContent">

<p>This is where content would go, should there be any.</p>

</div> <!-- end main content -->

EOF; // no space at start of this line

    print $page->getBottom();

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably have spaces after the terminator in your code examples, e.g.

```
[space]EOD;[space]
```

Also check the space before `EOD;`. i.e. you have to place your ending `heredoc` at the beginning of line.